# Running asynchronous functions once within express

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, express, promise

Is this the correct way to have asynchronous functions only run once within express? I don't want this function to have to run on every route. I'm looking for an express-friendly way to do this.

```
var packageJson = false
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.packageJson) return next()
  if(packageJson){
    req.packageJson = packageJson
    return next()
  }
  return fs.readFileAsync("./package.json", "utf8")
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then(function(data){
    packageJson = data
    req.packageJson = data
    return next()
  })  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even run the asynchronous function from within the first call to that route, but just do

```
var packageJson = fs.readFileAsync("./package.json", "utf8").then(JSON.parse);
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.packageJson)
    return next();
  else
    packageJson.then(function(data){
      req.packageJson = data;
      return next();
    });
});
```

But don't forget proper error handling, if that `packageJSON` promise is rejected your route might hang infinitely.

Comment: Since it's a JSON file I would probably use `require()` :-)

Comment: @robertklep: Yeah, maybe, but `require` is not asynchronous. Oh, and it would do the caching for us as well, so this feels like cheating :-)

Comment: But it's read into memory just once, after that the data is being served from memory which is basically the same as "storing" the data in a promise value (I agree somewhat with it being cheating though, it's not a generic solution).

Comment: Indeed. I wanted to show how to do it with any generic asynchronous function. `require` might be the better option for this particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference (this is not a generic solution, @Bergi's is), in this particular case you can use `require()`, which has two useful features:

- it can load JSON files directly
- it will cache the file data in memory

The middleware would look like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.packageJson = require('./package.json');
  return next();
});
```

The first request will take a small performance impact, as `require()` is synchronous, but for subsequent requests the data will be read from memory automatically.